# Help on a double integral with a rectangle domain

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral

Hello everyone I hope you are doing okay.

I have been stuck in this problem that I initially thought it was an easy problem

$$\int_{(0\ , \infty)\times(0\ , 1)}{\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy}$$

What i have tries so far is to apply Fulbini and further work it out, after applying it i arrive at

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^1{\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dy dx}$$

Then i think of trying to take the ArcTan out with $(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})^2$

but then i get stuck to $$\int_0^{\infty}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\arctan({{\sqrt{1+x^2}}})$$

and here i get stuck,  I would appreciate any kind of hints.

I know the integral converges because i put it in Mathematica

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interchange the limits and you'll get an easier integral since
$$\int_{(0\ , \infty)\times(0\ , 1)}{\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy}=\int_0^1\int_0^\infty{\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy}=\int_0^1\left(\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\biggr|_0^\infty\right)dy=\int_0^1\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{y^2+1}}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arcsinh}y\bigg|_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arcsinh}1$$